# Repeatedly calling a web service in mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el

I am working on a mule studio application in which I am calling a soap web service for getting status of a particular process. If the status is PENDING, I have to call the same web service until the status become COMPLETED. What approach I have to take for implementing this scenario.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the `until-successful` router: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Until+Successful+Scope

You can configure the `failureExpression` to check if the status is 'PENDING'.

Answer (score 0):

As Ryan Carter said, you can use the Until Successful router in order to achieve this.

You need to configure the failureExpression attribute to return 'true' if you want to call the web service again.

Note also that you can configure the until successful to be "synchronous" instead of the default "asynchronous". The former configuration does not require an object store.